# Build error with TensorFlow Android demo

Tags: android, tensorflow

Getting protobuf error while compiling TensorFlow Android demo
Using Android Studio on OSX.

Steps taken:

1. installed Bazel upgraded view brew
2. Cloned tensorflow repo with --recursive flags.
3. run .configure .
4. run the project

> Error:/private/var/tmp/_bazel_xxxxx/1b55123784db7232f203473c18395341/external/protobuf/BUILD:73:1:
>   C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf_lite' failed: false
>   failed: error executing command /bin/false -MD -MF
>   bazel-out/stub_armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/protobuf/_objs/protobuf_lite/external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.pic.d
>   ... (remaining 26 argument(s) skipped):
>   com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process
>   exited with status 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to also edit your WORKSPACE file with your NDK and SDK settings according to the directions at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android. /bin/false errors are typically seen when Bazel can't find the appropriate executable to run, in this case the ndk gcc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick way to build the TensorFlow Android demo, you can follow the instructions I wrote in this blog post:
https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-2-9ec0698d801e#.a7kxjliws

To help make this easier, I've created a Docker image that has all the dependencies and configuration you need, so you should just be able to install Docker, download my Docker image, then build.  Good luck!

```
docker pull danjarvis/tensorflow-android:1.0.0
```